# If an application uses the targetSdkVersion:"17" in manifest file, Can it run in devices with the higher API levels?

Tags: android

I know that the `minSdkVersion` and the  `targetSdkVersion` are what. But My system is weak and it can not run the new version of the android studio that it can supports the higher API levels than the `17 API level`.

Currently, I have the older version of the android studio and it runs in my system well but it supports only up to the `17 API level`. I do not need the higher API levels. Now my question is, If I use the `targetSdkVersion:"17"` for an application, can it run in devices with the higher API levels?

Answer (score 0):

> But My system is weak and it can not run the new version of the android studio that it can supports the higher API levels than the 17 API level.

AFAIK, Android Studio's speed has nothing to do with any API levels in the project that you are building.

> Now my question is, If I use the targetSdkVersion:"17" for an application, can it run in devices with the higher API levels?

Yes.